# What is Titus and what issues does it solve?

Tags: terminology, titus

I read an article from [Medium Titled "The Evolution of Container Usage at Netflix"](https://medium.com/netflix-techblog/the-evolution-of-container-usage-at-netflix-3abfc096781b) and watched a couple of videos on the topic, but it is unclear to me why Titus (referenced in these) should be used. Is it different than Kubernetes or should it be used in concert with Kubernetes?

Comment: May worth a read: https://fr.slideshare.net/aspyker/netflix-and-containers-titus

Comment: [Titus, the Netflix container management platform, is now open source](https://medium.com/@NetflixTechBlog/titus-the-netflix-container-management-platform-is-now-open-source-f868c9fb5436)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's different to Kubernetes in that it seeks to leverage existing AWS services instead of bolting on top. Kubernetes supports a number of cloud providers and contains a number of components that exist in AWS already.

Although we're starting to see better kubernetes AWS integration and with AWS joining the cloud native foundation this is only going to get stronger.

Titus seems to be an alternative to Kubernetes but its not available yet. My bet is AWS will strive to better integrate K8 and likely Titus won't take off even when it is released.

Answer (score 0):

Titus is been kept in the dark, for now, I guess mostly because we are kind of used to see these cool tools from [Netflix in the OSS scene](https://netflix.github.io/), not the case for Titus, yet. If you want to know more about what Netflix's plan is for Titus, I think [this](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=14528374) is worth reading.

Comment: Hi Ernesto, welcome to this site and thank you for answering this question!  I would like to encourage you rewrite a bit your answer so that it provides useful information on its own (even without reading the HackerNews article you are linking to). So you could add 1-2 sentences outlining the content of the HackerNews article. Also be sure to give explicitly an answer to the questions asked (what are the strengths or typical use-cases for Titus, how does it relate to Kubernetes). With this, your input will be even more useful to other visitors!